# What is and causes the "eerie noise" sound effect?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While mining i saw "eerie noise" appear in the subtitles (new feature of 1.9 showing game sounds; i keep it on as i like my volume low). I am unable to recreate it, although not much time was put into it, and so i assume it is rare and possible for aesthetics.

What causes it? And does it signal anything?

Comment: When does it usually occur? During cave diving sessions? If this is what I think it is, it usually signifies a (dark/undiscovered) cave nearby.

Comment: I've only noticed it once which was going up a stairway from a mine, which could really be anywhere, but you suggestion of it being undiscovered areas sounds interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few sounds that *could* be listed as "eerie", and (from the explanation in the comments) *generally* appear near undiscovered caves.

From the [wiki:](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ambience)<sup>[1]</sup>

> Ambient sounds can play in a space of any size, but they seem to play much more likely in larger spaces positioned 10 - 20 blocks away from the player in any direction, and completely filled with a light level less than 8 without any lighting from the sky (the ambience will more likely play from the direction of lower levels because of a lower light level).

So, while these sounds can occur at any level, in any structure, just so long as the light level is below 8, these "Ambient" sounds can appear.

---

[1]: This link also has a list of all the "Ambient" sound tracks for comparison.